# Proving Finiteness

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

1. For any set $X$, if $\cup X$ is finite, then $P(X)$ (power set of X) is finite.
2. For any Transitive set $X$, if $P(X)$ is finite, then $\cup X$ is finite.

I'm a little confused with these because I've never come across an example that doesn't start with $X$ being finite so I'm unsure of how to make the step between $\cup X$ and $P(X)$.

For question 1, I was thinking:

Let $K$ be a collection of subsets of $P(\cup X)$ satisfying $\forall B \in K, \cup B\text{ is finite}$.

Then $\emptyset$ is an element of $K$ and $B \cup {x}$ is in $K$ for all $x$ in $X$. Therefore $K$ is Kuratowski Inductive and, as $\cup X$ is finite, $\cup X \in K$ and so $\cup\cup X$ is finite. 
As $P(X) \subseteq \cup\cup X$, this implies $P(X)$ is finite.

Is this right? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: There are multiple definitions of "finite." Which one are you using here? Or is any definition allowed here (even though they are not all equivalent)?

Comment: I'm using the definition X is finite if X ∈ K for all Kuratowski inductive subsets of PX.

Comment: You're working too hard.